# Get stock from Purchased and Sold Products QTY

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been working on Client project. I need to get stock from Purchased product QTY and Sold QTY.

Here my SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_itemmaster.product_code,tbl_itemmaster.unittype,tbl_itemmaster.color,SUM(tbl_purchasedetails.qty),SUM(tbl_saledetails.qty),(SUM(tbl_purchasedetails.qty)-SUM(tbl_saledetails.qty)) 
FROM (tbl_itemmaster LEFT JOIN tbl_saledetails ON tbl_itemmaster.[product_code] = tbl_saledetails.[product_code]) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_purchasedetails ON tbl_itemmaster.[product_code]=tbl_purchasedetails.[product_code] GROUP BY tbl_itemmaster.product_code,tbl_itemmaster.unittype,tbl_itemmaster.color
```

Below is the result of sql

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Product Code   Unit Type  Color     Purchase QTY  Sold QTY  Stock
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1001           KiloGram   Red       500           
500            Kilogram   White     1033          300       733
570            Kilogram   Black   
600            Kilogram   Pink   
9005           Kilogram   Magenta   800.5         
900            Kilogram   Green   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Product code **500** has three times purchase entry i.e. 500+400+133 = 1033 Purchased Qty

Product code **500** has only ONE time sale entry i.e. 100 = 100 Sold Qty

Product code **500** suppose to has **933** Stock Qty

BUT why I getting 300 in sold qty ?

Where my query is lacking?

PLEASE HELP !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting cartesian products, because products have multiple sales and purchases.

The solution is to do the aggregation *before* the join:

```
SELECT im.product_code, im.unittype, im.color,
       pd purchaseqty, sd.salesqty),
       (purchaseqty - salesqty)
FROM (tbl_itemmaster as im LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT product_code, SUM(qty) as salesqty
       FROM tbl_saledetails
       GROUP BY product_code
      ) as sd
      ON im.[product_code] = sd.[product_code]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT product_code, SUM(qty) as purchaseqty
      FROM tbl_purchasedetails
      GROUP BY product_code
     ) as pd
     ON im.[product_code] = pd.[product_code];
```